# Android database plan

Tags: android, android-studio, android-database

At this point I want my first app to get the user interactions and store it to SQLite database. here is the idea. I kept 15 activity from which my plan is to take user input and save it in the database and display them with a list view in the respective activity. so my question is if I'm to get the user input from 15 different activity and save it into a table and display it in the respective activities? should I make a different table for different activity input or make one table and save it there? if the second one will be the best plan then how do I do it?

detail of the app.....
we have 10 branches, 2 warehouses & 1 HO. In the HO i have like 5 departments. i want to keep the employee record from all the branches, warehouses and HO and store them into the database.

thanks...

Comment: If your data are different than make different table if not then make single table and store data and show data according to screen with query and selected value.

Comment: Also used room database it easy and it is similar to sqlite db.

Comment: You should use room database it easy to store and updates your UI automatically whenever data got changed by using Live Data with Room .